# Postgresql Query - select json

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql query that I want to save as .json, just from a especific part of the query result:

```
SELECT info FROM d.tests where tag like 'HMIZP'
```

The result of this query is:

```
{"blabla":{a lot of blabla}, "Body":[{....
```

I just want everything after "Body" (including " Body")

How can I do it?

Comment: "*including `Body`*" - why? Do you want the entire JSON object, without the `blabla` key, or do you want only the value of the `Body` property? Why would you want to include its key, which is known already? Are you really looking for string operations, getting malformed JSON back, or do you want a JSON value?

Comment: I am having a bad time trying to get a dataframe in pandas with the result of the entire json.  Its a deep nested dicts and the useful information I need comes after Body.  What i really need it to be able to read it in pandas and create a dataframe from it.

Comment: And it's stored in the database as JSON? Then just use `SELECT info -> 'Body'`

Comment: I guess its not Json because info -> 'Body' returns <null>. This task is killing me lol !

Comment: i uploaded an image of the record I have.  Theres tons of nested dict before Body...

Comment: Seems to be JSON - if it wasn't, that expression would have thrown an error instead of returning `null`.

Comment: The screenshot is not really helpful, since it doesn't show where the body itself is. However, it looks like a JSON representation of an XML document (really, [the `xml` type might have been more appropriate), which suggests that the body you're looking for is actually nested *inside* those structures, not just after them. You might want to use JSONpath if you're on a modern Postgres version.

Comment: I tried everything: xml, json, tried to open the file using excel everthing, nothing work properly :-(

Comment: well, i think i did:  info #> '{env:Envelope,Body}

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the extraction with building a json

> ```
> SELECT json_build_object('Body',json_extract_path('{"blabla": {   "a": "a lot of blabla"},"Body": [{"a": [1,2]}, {"b":2}]}','Body'))
> ```
>
> ```
> | json_build_object                  |
> | :--------------------------------- |
> | {"Body" : [{"a": [1,2]}, {"b":2}]} |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=249bf4b9f8df3bb5110263bfadf41992)*